# SQL Server: Performing OUTER APPLY between two subqueries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to get results from two subqueries using an OUTER Apply but it does not work. Below I put the skeleton of the query i am trying to do as an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.Field1, D.Field2, S.Field1, S.Field2
FROM (
        SELECT Field1, Field2
        FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.CommonField = t2.CommonField
                       INNER JOIN Table3 t3 on t3.CommonField = t2.CommonField
                       LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 on t4.CommonField = t3.CommonField
        WHERE t1.Date > '20181011'

     ) D OUTER APPLY
     (
        SELECT Field1, Field2
        FROM Table5 t5 INNER JOIN Table6 t6 on t6.CommonField = t5.CommonField
                       INNER JOIN Table7 t7 on t7.CommonField = t6.CommonField
        WHERE t5.Field4 = 'SomeWhat'
        GROUP BY t5.Date
     ) S
```

SQL Server parser give me an error:
Icorrect syntax near 'D'.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The "skeleton" looks syntactically OK. Problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What's that GROUP BY doing in there? You're not selecting t5.Date and you're not aggregating...

Comment: I suspect that this is an anonymised query (who would really name all their objects `table{n}`, `field{n}`, and `commonfield` and not go crazy after a few hours because they have no idea what is what anymore), and the OP has anonymised it so much it's become a valid query (apart from the `GROUP BY` issue that @LordPeter mentioned). Post your *actual* query, not one that represents it, but doesn't show the problem you're having.

Comment: where is the relation between query s and query d?

Comment: Hi all, very sorry. I have not posted the real query because it is confidential. I have solved it, it was a missing parenthesis. Very sorry again, and a lot of thanks for your suggestion and support.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks okay, except that you've used `GROUP BY  t5.Date`, but selecting other columns such as `Field1, Field2`. Just add  these columns into `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM Table5 t5 INNER JOIN Table6 t6 on t6.CommonField = t5.CommonField
INNER JOIN Table7 t7 on t7.CommonField = t6.CommonField
WHERE t5.Field4 = 'SomeWhat'
GROUP BY t5.Date, t5.Field1, t5.Field2
```

Let me show a work example:

```
DECLARE  @TableA TABLE (
  id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  value nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE  @TableB TABLE (
  id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  value nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
  tableARid BIGINT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TableA(value) VALUES('test');
INSERT INTO @TableB(value, tableARid) VALUES ('test1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TableB(value, tableARid) VALUES ('test2', 1);
INSERT INTO @TableB(value, tableARid) VALUES ('test3', 1);

SELECT
  subQuery.id
, subQuery.value
, oa.id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      ta.id
    , ta.value
    FROM @TableA ta
) subQuery
OUTER APPLY 
(
   SELECT 
     tb.id
   , tb.value 
   FROM @TableB tb   
   GROUP BY tb.id, tb.[value]
) oa
```